# Not sure If my solution is right or wrong

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, html-lists, navigationbar

I want the links to cover area from top to bottom of navigation bar what is happening on all the links except the Dropdown one.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta name="description" content="This is a example site for nav design">
    <title>
      Navbar
    </title>
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      nav {
        background-color: #f1f5f9;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        width: 100%;
        box-shadow: 0rem .15rem  .25rem #94a3b8;
      }
      .nav {
        margin-left:10%;
        margin-right:10%;
      }
      .nav a {
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: #1e293b;
        font-weight: 600;
        padding: 1rem;
      }
      nav ul {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: right;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
      }
      nav ul li {
        padding: 1rem;
      }
      .nav a:hover, .nav .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
        color: #6b7280;
      }
      .nav .dropdown {
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0;
      }
      .nav .dropdown .dropbtn {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 600;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        color: #1e293b;
        background-color: inherit;
        font-family: inherit;
      }
      .dropdown-items {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f1f5f9;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        z-index: 1;
      }
      .nopadding {
        padding: 0;
      }
      .nav .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
        color: #6b7280;
      }
      .dropdown-items a {
        float: none;
        color: #6b7280;
        padding: 1rem 1rem 1rem 1rem;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
        box-shadow: 0px .15rem .15rem #e2e8f0;
      }
      .dropdown-items a:hover {
        color: #1e293b;
        background-color: #f8fafc;
      }
      .dropdown:hover .dropdown-items {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
    <!--
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://livejs.com/live.js"></script>
    -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <div class="nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Content</a></li>
          <li>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="dropbtn">Social</button>
              <div class="dropdown-items">
                <a href="#">Instagram</a>
                <a href="#">Twitter</a>
                <a href="#">Facebook</a>
                <a href="#">Youtube</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

  </body>
</html>
```

It is working as intended if I change the third list tag and place is just before the Social link.

```
    <nav>
      <div class="nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Content</a></li>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="dropbtn">
                <li>Social</li>
              </button>
              <div class="dropdown-items">
                <a href="#">Instagram</a>
                <a href="#">Twitter</a>
                <a href="#">Facebook</a>
                <a href="#">Youtube</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

It's working but I am not sure if it is a good way like adding other tags before list tag for a list item and when I run lighthouse test it also says list tag requires unordered list tag and cannot be used alone.

So I want to know, If there is a way to get the desired functionality of the lator Html code through Css.

Comment: Hi, please put your code through a validator and sort out the HTML - it has several errors e.g. look up what element(s) can and cannot be the child(ren) of a ul element. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul is a reliable source.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The code above without passes all the tests and does not have any errors on validator.w3.org and my question is can i get the desired function of the lator Html code through Css.

Comment: There are a couple of errors in your HTML, starting with a div cannot be the (direct) child of a ul.

Comment: Now I do understand that the later code is wrong. So can I implement that functionality in the upper code which is right using Css or if there is other way to implement the same functionality in html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some changes I got the results I wanted.
New code:

```css
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      nav {
        background-color: #f1f5f9;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        width: 100%;
        box-shadow: 0rem .15rem  .25rem #94a3b8;
      }
      .nav {
        margin-left:15%;
        margin-right:15%;
      }
      .nav a {
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: #1e293b;
        font-weight: 600;
        padding: 1rem;
      }
      nav ul {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;  /* Aligned items in center of navbar */
        justify-content: right;
        list-style-type: none;
      }
      /* Removed nav ul li padding of 1rem */
      .nav a:hover, .nav .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
        color: #6b7280;
      }
      .nav .dropdown {
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0;
      }
      .nav .dropdown .dropbtn {
        padding: 1rem;  /* Added padding to dropdown button */
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 600;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        color: #1e293b;
        background-color: inherit;
        font-family: inherit;
      }
      .dropdown-items {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f1f5f9;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        z-index: 1;
      }
      .nopadding {
        padding: 0;
      }
      .nav .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
        color: #6b7280;
      }
      .dropdown-items a {
        float: none;
        color: #6b7280;
        padding: 1rem 1rem 1rem 1rem;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
        box-shadow: 0px .15rem .15rem #e2e8f0;
      }
      .dropdown-items a:hover {
        color: #1e293b;
        background-color: #f8fafc;
      }
      .dropdown:hover .dropdown-items {
        display: block;
      }
```

```html
  <body>
    <nav>
      <div class="nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Content</a></li>
          <li>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="dropbtn">Social</button>
              <div class="dropdown-items">
                <a href="#">Instagram</a>
                <a href="#">Twitter</a>
                <a href="#">Facebook</a>
                <a href="#">Youtube</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
  </body>
```

1. Removed padding from unordered list items.
2. Added align-items center to unordered list to center the items on navbar.
3. Added 1rem padding to dropbtn class.